# Why would Opera browser mark my website as unsafe?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, browser

I was wondering why would Opera browser mark my website as an safe? it shows the following message: blocked insecure content, Opera has blocked content that comes from insecure sources. but there is nothing blocked on my website

my website uses (https://) url and all links and scripts are from google only like font and adsense script.

Im hosting my website with a very popular hosting provider and i use their cpanel mysql database.

my website has no login form and the only input field is for the search bar and I made sure to use mysqli_real_escape and prepared statements.

Opera browser and explorer are displaying this message, firefox, chrome and safari are all good.
is there anything i can do to make my website Opera and explorer secure?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing all of the code, but it looks like it will throw that error if any of the links you are including use http instead of https: https://forums.opera.com/topic/30333/opera-browser-blocked-insecure-content-what-is-it-how-to-see/2?_=1582559171791&lang=en-US

Comment: check the rendered HTML code, and check the network panel. Do you see any that have http? BTW start links without specifying protocol, like `<a href="//google.com" >` and it will automatically use the correct protocol

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're referring to http:// resources within your page as the others said. This is a behaviour that it's getting punished (being intentional or not) by the newest versions of the browsers more and more as it is considered insecure.

Indeed, there are plans for Chrome itself to start banning sites with that behaviour progressively, i.e.: first you'll get that insecure warnings (already happening), but the plan is to eventually ban them and force a fully-compliant https site, with all the links going also to https resources (i.e.: no http allowed). Please see [this link](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/8/16991254/chrome-not-secure-marked-http-encryption-ssl) or [this one](https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/milestone-chrome-security-marking-http-not-secure/) for details.

Oh, btw, Opera is now Chrome (Chromium) based, so I'd expect to go with the same road/plan.